# Get only the second last argument of the previous command

Tags: bash

```
[ -f /root/.bash_aliases ] || echo "$_"
```

gives me `]`

I want `/root/.bash_aliases`

I also tried

```
[ -f /root/.bash_aliases ] || echo !:2
```

but it gives me the following result

```
[ -f /root/.bash_aliases ] || echo /root/.bash_aliases
/root/.bash_aliases
```

I only want `/root/.bash_aliases`

Answer (score 4):

That's the kind of thing functions are made for:

```
print_if_not_regular() {
  [ -f "$1" ] || printf '%s\n' "$1"
}
print_if_not_regular /root/.bash_aliases
```

Some shells like `es` or `zsh` have anonymous functions:

```
(){[ -f "$1" ] || printf '%s\n' $1} /root/.bash_aliases # zsh
@ {[ -f $1 ] || printf '%s\n' $1} /root/.bash_aliases # es
```

I'd avoid using `$_`. It no longer works if you have a DEBUG trap for instance.

```
$ bash -c 'trap ": \"\$((cmdcount+=1))\"" DEBUG; echo foo; echo "$_"'
foo
2
```

Note that `!:n` is not the n<sup>th</sup> argument of the last command, but the n<sup>th</sup> lexical token of the previous command line (the last line (possibly even multiline) stored into the history). For instance, in

```
echo $(echo A B)
echo foo; echo !:1
```

That `!:1` is not expanded to `foo` (the last argument of the last command), nor `B` (the last argument of the `echo` from the `echo` command of the previous command line), but `$(echo A B)`. Here you'd need to enter:

```
[ -f /root/.bash_aliases ] ||
  echo !:2
```

That is, enter it on separate lines. Here, it happens to work (by accident) even though the history line is not fully complete by the time you enter that second line. That same trick doesn't work in `(t)csh` (where history  expansions comes from), nor `zsh`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
test -f /root/.bash_aliases || echo "$_"
```

or

```
test -f /root/.bash_aliases || printf '%s\n' "$_"
```

`$_` will expand to the last argument of the previous command.  In your example, the previous command is `[` and its last argument is `]`.

Above, the last command is `test` and its last argument is the filename.

`test` and `[` are the same commands, but `[` requires a `]` as its last command line argument. In this case, this is what makes it difficult to use `$_` to get at the filename.

The above solution has the benefit of working in at least `bash` (unless you have a `DEBUG` trap set) and `zsh`.

---

If you have the filename in a variable, it would be trivial to do

```
[ -f "$name" ] || printf '%s\n' "$name"
```

or

```
if [ ! -f "$name" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$name"
fi
```

depending on your preference for `if` statements and short-circuit logic tests.

Comment: Thanks for your time Kusal, your answer although solves my problem but was expecting something on the lines where I could use `[ ... ]` and no variable assignments, seems like there isn't a way to do that way..

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut The _simple_ solution is to switch to using `test` (which is equivalent to `[` except that it doesn't need `]`). The complicated solution involves trying to get history expansion work the way you want it to.

Comment: That `$_` feature is neither Bourne nor POSIX nor Korn.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No it's not, although it works in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`.  I will remove the particular wording about being "portable" though.

Comment: Not in ksh AFAICS

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But in `pdksh`... I was wrongly assuming that it would work in `ksh93` just because it worked in `pdksh`. Fixed now. Still early Saturday morning...

Comment: In pdksh, only when interactive. Not in posh (based on pdksh)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, but in `bash` and `zsh` it would work in scripts, right?

Comment: Yes, but in bash, only if you don't have a DEBUG trap, or that DEBUG trap runs no simple command in the current environment.